Finding it hard to move large files onto USB storage
I use Linux Mint Debian Edition Faye, and I've recently been trying to move some 4 hours of footage (4.9GB worth) to a USB for physical storage. It's one consecutive mp4 file but it always tends to copy roughly 4.3/4.9GB before stopping and never starting again. I've tried leaving it to see if it restarts but it never does. I've attempted to see if the 64GB USB I'm using is a phony and actually has less storage, but "df -h" and "df -B1" both show that it's a 59GB drive. So what could be going on to significantly slow the copying speed?

What format is the USB drive?

What file system runs on that USB stick?
Likely, that's FAT which has a maximum file size of 4,294,967,295 bytes. There's no way to fit a 4.9 GB file.
You need to either reformat the stick with a more suitable and mutually accepted file system, break the file into at least two pieces, or use an archive tool with multiple volumes. For instance, you could run zip -0 -s 3g <destinationpath/archive> <videofile>.  -0 uses no compression (speed up, video won't compress anyway), and -s 3g creates 3 GB chunks.
A phony USB stick is another possibility, but it wouldn't usually cause that error. You'd need to test the stick by e.g. running f3write/f3read. With a completely empty stick you could alternatively use fwprobe --destructive which is much faster.

You can also format the drive exFAT, if the Linux exFAT fuse module has been installed (or ext4, NTFS, etc.).

If FAT were the problem, the next write would immediately fail. It would not get stuck forever.

@grawity Why should the next attempt fail? Copying goes on until the maximum size is reached, then the next buffer write fails. When you retry, the file gets rewritten from start, with the same result.

The 4,294,967,295 bytes are what OP sees with his 4.3 GB of 4.9 GB copied. This is no coincidence. The error also fits the situation of copying large files onto FAT media -- I know from experience. exFAT is now native on Linux, OP should try it.

I just formatted the drive as exFAT (using Mint USB Formatter), but when I insert my USB I get the error of "Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/XXXXX/USB: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb1"? Any ideas - Thanks
I just reformatted it, there must have been some error during the formatting because it's all good now. Thank you all for helping.

@PatrickDunmall Please don't forget to eventually accept an answer. (And you may vote for any useful ones, too.)
